# How to extract daily pricing data of bonds from Bloomberg Terminal based on a list of ISIN-numbers?

Tags: bloomberg

I have a list of ISIN-numbers (as well as other information like issue date, maturity etc.) for 384 Swedish and Norwegian bonds in Excel. I would like to extract daily bid price, ask price and ask yield for all 384 bonds (starting from the issue date and ending at the maturity date) from the Bloomberg Terminal. I am familiar with the existence of the Excel add-in but I do not know how to use it. I have access to Bloomberg Terminal through my university.

Does anyone know if this is possible. If yes, how?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @mypetlion Yes, like the topic states I wonder how I can extract the data I am looking for from Bloomberg.

Answer (score 1):

`=BDH (security, fields, start date, end date, [optional argument(s)])`

Check the Help page in Excel for BDH() for details on syntax and examples.

Comment: Is there a way of choosing the start to be the issue date?

Answer (score 1):

First of all please note that you have daily limits on the amount of data that can be downloaded into Excel, without requiring your University to pay for additional Data Licence services.

Requesting bid price, ask price, ask yield every day from issue to maturity for a list of 384 instruments will very likely breach the limit and have Bloomberg representatives coming over to speak with the Department.

That said...! Retrieving the data you want is very simple. The basic formula structure you will need is:

```
=BDH("Instrument ID","Data Field","Start Date","End Date", [optional arguments])
```

Let's say you have ISIN GB0003252318. You need to append an additional identifier to the end of this string to let Bloomberg know what it relates to. In this case, you merely need to append the word "ISIN" to the end. So your Instrument ID would be "GB0003252318 ISIN".

For Data Fields, go to the FLDS screen on Bloomberg. This is where you can look up all API fields and their definitions. Off the top of my head I cannot remember for sure, but I believe the bid price field is "BID_PX" (and "ASK_PX" for ask). Double check on the FLDS screen for yourself.

Then fill in the dates part of the formula, and you should retrieve a time series of the requested data. For example, your formula might look like:

```
=BDH("GB0003252318 ISIN","PX_BID","20100101","")
```

By leaving the 'end date' field blank (in quotation marks), it will look for the latest data available. Of course you can instead hard code an end date of your choosing.

Additional points to consider: 
The =BDH formula stands for "Bloomberg Data History", and is used when you want to pull historical data through the API. There is also a =BDP formula, "Bloomberg Data Point", for when you just need to grab one bit of data for an instrument. Like, ahem, issue date or maturity date.

```
=BDP("GB0003252318 ISIN","Data Field")
```

You could perhaps pull these two data points per ISIN, and then reference these in the date fields of the =BDH formulas.

But I will leave that down to you.